# How to compare custom classes: Creating a simple card game

Tags: python, class

I'm trying to create a simple card game, where each player, in this case the user and the pc, each get 20 cards out of 54, and the first cards are automaticly put out and compared. Hers is my current code:

```
import random
tolvuspil=[]
notandaspil=[]
stokkur= []


class Card:
def __init__(self, suit, val):
    self.suit = suit
    self.value = val

def show(self):
    print("{} {}".format(self.suit, self.value))


class deck:
def __init__(self):
    self.cards = []
    self.build()

def build(self):
    for s in ['Hjarta', 'Spaða', 'Tígul', 'Laufa']:
        for v in range(1, 14):
            if v == 11:
                v = "Jock"
            elif v == 1:
                v = "ace"
            elif v == 12:
                v = "Quenn"
            elif v == 13:
                v = "King"
            self.cards.append(Card(s, v))


def show(self):
    for c in self.cards:
        c.show()

def shuffle(self):
    for i in range(len(self.cards) -1 , 0, -1):
        r= random.randint(0, i)
        self.cards[i], self.cards[r] = self.cards[r], self.cards[i]


def drawcard(self):
    return self.cards.pop()


class player:
def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name
    self.hand = []a

def draw(self, deck):
    self.hand.append(deck.drawcard())
    return self

def showhand(self):
    for card in self.hand:
        card.show()

 boblisti = []
 xyz = deck()
 xyz.shuffle()
 xyz.show()
```

This code does what it is supposed to do, which is generating a deck of cards, but i am having a hard time working with the cards them self. I want to put the in a list or string, where i can store both the suit and value data, so i can compere them, as some values beat other and every game on suit will be superior to others.

Comment: What is the code doing instead of what it's supposed to do? It's easier to debug code when you know what error it is producing.

Comment: There's a handful of requirements there.  It would be easier to answer, and you'd be happier with the answer if you spelled out a few specific sub-problems you are trying to solve.

For instance:

"Randomly deal out 20 cards out of a set of 54."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can improve your quality of life with these cards by implementing the [dunder methods (a.k.a. magic methods)](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#basic-customization) for the object. Using some liberties, I've implemented one possible way that you could compare the cards. Once you've implemented the dunder methods, you can compare `Card`s just like you would `str`s or `int`s.

```py
import random
tolvuspil = []
notandaspil = []
stokkur = []
boblisti = []


class Card:

    values = ["ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10" ,"Jock", "Quenn", "King"] # in order, least valuable to most.
    suits = ['Tígul', 'Laufa', 'Hjarta', 'Spaða'] # in order, least valuable to most.

    def __init__(self, suit, val):
        suit = str(suit) # input normalization
        val = str(val) # input normalization
        assert suit in self.suits, "Suit [found %s] must be in suits: %s" % (suit, ", ".join(self.suits))
        assert val in self.values, "Value [found %s] must be in values: %s" % (val, ", ".join(self.values))
        self.suit = suit 
        self.value = val

    def show(self):
        print(self)

    def __eq__(self, other): # == operator
        return other.suit == self.suit and other.value == self.value

    def __ne__(self, other): # != operator
        return not (self == other)

    def __lt__(self, other): # < operator
        if self.value == other.value: # first, compare the face value
            # if they have the same face value, compare their suits
            return self.suits.index(self.suit) < self.suits.index(other.suit)
        return self.values.index(self.value) < self.values.index(other.value)

    def __le__(self, other): # <= operator
        return self == other or self < other

    def __gt__(self, other): # > operator
        if self.value == other.value: # first, compare the face value
            # if they have the same face value, compare their suits
            return self.suits.index(self.suit) > self.suits.index(other.suit)
        return self.values.index(self.value) > self.values.index(other.value)

    def __ge__(self, other): # >= operator
        return self == other or self > other

    def __str__(self): # str() implementation
        return "{} {}".format(self.suit, self.value)

class deck:

    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []
        self.build()

    def build(self):
        for s in ['Hjarta', 'Spaða', 'Tígul', 'Laufa']:
            for v in range(1, 14):
                if v == 11:
                    v = "Jock"
                elif v == 1:
                    v = "ace"
                elif v == 12:
                    v = "Quenn"
                elif v == 13:
                    v = "King"
                self.cards.append(Card(s, v))

    def show(self):
        for c in self.cards:
            print(c)

    def shuffle(self):
        for i in range(len(self.cards) - 1, 0, -1):
            r = random.randint(0, i)
            self.cards[i], self.cards[r] = self.cards[r], self.cards[i]

    def drawcard(self):
        return self.cards.pop()


class player:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.hand = []

    def draw(self, deck):
        self.hand.append(deck.drawcard())
        return self

    def showhand(self):
        for card in self.hand:
            card.show()


xyz = deck()
xyz.shuffle()
xyz.show()

a = xyz.drawcard()
b = xyz.drawcard()

print(a, b)

print("a < b:", a < b)
print("a <= b:", a <= b)
print("a > b:", a > b)
print("a >= b:", a >= b)
print("a == b:", a == b)
print("a != b:", a != b)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how the game should work but there were a lot of errors. Other than the indentation error. You added an extra "a" in the self.hand in def **init**() of the player class.

```
import random
tolvuspil = []
notandaspil = []
stokkur = []
boblisti = []


class Card:

    def __init__(self, suit, val):
        self.suit = suit
        self.value = val

    def show(self):
        print("{} {}".format(self.suit, self.value))


class deck:

    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []
        self.build()

    def build(self):
        for s in ['Hjarta', 'Spaða', 'Tígul', 'Laufa']:
            for v in range(1, 14):
                if v == 11:
                    v = "Jock"
                elif v == 1:
                    v = "ace"
                elif v == 12:
                    v = "Quenn"
                elif v == 13:
                    v = "King"
                self.cards.append(Card(s, v))

    def show(self):
        for c in self.cards:
            c.show()

    def shuffle(self):
        for i in range(len(self.cards) - 1, 0, -1):
            r = random.randint(0, i)
            self.cards[i], self.cards[r] = self.cards[r], self.cards[i]

    def drawcard(self):
        return self.cards.pop()


class player:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.hand = []

    def draw(self, deck):
        self.hand.append(deck.drawcard())
        return self

    def showhand(self):
        for card in self.hand:
            card.show()


xyz = deck()
xyz.shuffle()
xyz.show()
```